# Embedding files in Keynote

Tags: macos, keynote

Is there any way to embed files in Keynote presentation? So, that others can click on it and download/open it in their machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides images or other media that can natively be placed into Keynote, for a document or binary file of arbitrary format, you would almost certainly have to post it elsewhere (Dropbox/Google/web page) and embed a URL to the sharing link in your presentation.

Unfortunately, it seems you can't make the URL have the format of `file://` instead of `http://` You can, however use `ftp://` or `sftp://` or `smb://` !

Comment: on modern versions of keynote, you can use pseudo links like /Users/john/Desktop/test.pdf. note there is no file:/// part. to open such a pseudo link, select it, open its context menu, choose 'services' and then 'open' (something like this. i'm not at home currently)

Comment: Interesting! You should post that as a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

On modern versions of Keynote, you can use pseudo links like `/Users/johndoe/Desktop/test.pdf`. Note there is no `file:///` part (this won't work). To open such a pseudo link, select it, open its context menu, choose 'Services' and then 'Open URL' for Safari or 'Open' for Finder.